# Cells capacity and current max draw

Tags: power-supply, batteries, current

Can you draw 12mA from a `CR2032` (or `RL44`) cell for long time? The data sheets says **~240mAH** means about 24 hours to 2V, but it says that for draw less than **1mA** typical...

And if there is no max, can I calculate the capacity — `mAH`, as a const, or does it change according to the current draw?

Does **pulses** draw is better or worse for capacity?

Is there a "home" (a place where you put that battery into such as other cells have)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, higher current you draw, lower the capacity is. That is because when the call get discharged, the internal resistance becomes higher and the voltage drop as well.

Anyway, in general, the cell developers always try to increase this effect and to lower the internal impedance. But sometimes it is not easy task, together with the other parameters of the cell, for example the shelf life.

That is why there are many types of cells and you should choose the type you need for your application. The corresponding data sheet must contain a data about maximal allowed current and how the capacity is affected by the current.

Mentioned CR2032 is designed to provide small currents for low power electronic devices for very long time with very low selfdischarge. It means that probably you should not use it with very high currents. 20..30mA is the maximum on my estimation.

Comment: that is strange because there are many key holders that uses that battery for a light, and a led is always takes at least 10mA . anyway, i am looking for a battery for a micro controller that takes 12mA and 3-5v and that it will be as much smaller as could be .

Comment: Well, 10mA is not outside my estimation of 20..30mA max. :) Although, It seems this cell suitable for your project very well.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume a good quality CR2032, from Energizer, the charge capacity is specified for 0.2mA.
current draw.
If you try to take more than that, the capacity will be smaller.
See the 2nd page of the datasheet http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/cr2032.pdf

There is a battery housing, check Renata, Keystone or many others.

Comment: Wow I thought the op meant something like a retirement home for old, nearly spent cells!

Comment: Well, not everyone is a native Englishman, speaking the queen's dialect..

Comment: I've met very few of them. Hey I was trying to make a joke as much at me as anything!